# jQuery Function to dynamically load more data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

so I followed an old youtube tutorial but I'm not able to do it exactly. Nothing's loading on my end. Basically, what I want to do is post 3 or 5 data from database on a webpage and then when the user scrolls down, it will load even more data (I want to make a button stating(load more) then call the function to load it). 
Right now, my webpage is blank nothing is popping out, even errors, nothing.
Wandering for almost an hour changing things and double checking but to no avail.
Any assistance is highly appreciated :)
Here is my index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //var to auto-increment 
                var flag = 0;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "get_data.php",
                    data:{
                        'offset': 0,
                        'limit': 3
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('body').append(data);
                        flag += 3;
                    }

                });

                $(window).scroll(function(){

                    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

                    $.ajax({

                        type: "GET",
                        url: "get_data.php",
                        data:{
                            'offset': flag,
                            'limit': 3
                            },
                        success: function(data){
                        $('body').append(data);
                        flag += 3;
                            }

                    });

                }
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

        .blog-post{
            border-bottom: solid 4px black;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .blog-post h1{
            font-zise: 40px;
        }
        .blog-post p{
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>


 </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

see link for the "get_data.php": https://pastebin.com/MYz2bjFN
jquery.min.js is on the same folder as well as the get_data.php.
database is existing.

Comment: Do you get any js errors in the developer console? Do you get any PHP errors in the error log? Have you checked the network tab in the developer tools to see if a request is made at all or what it actually returns?

Comment: You should also include all relevant code in the question itself, not as a link to an external service. If the external link changes/stops working, this question might become useless for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, I'm checking the network tab of developer tools, uncaught exception on the end line.

Comment: Please add the complete (important) error message to your question. Also, please add your PHP code directly into the question as well.

Comment: ohh man, I saw it already, thanks for the tip.. I just added });  before the </script> tag. But not sure what's the point of it because all tags are closed already. I will post another comment.

Comment: If you use some proper indention, you can see that it's the `$(window).scroll(function(){...` that doesn't gets closed.

Comment: I'm using tabs tabs for indention, basically it's wrong, do you use any plugin on notepad++ for auto indent? Now it's working when i scroll it, it now loads another set of data

Comment: I don't use notepad++. I'm using Sublime. Btw, since you found the issue yourself, create an answer and just explain how you solved it and mark it as answered.

Comment: Will do, thank you man :) you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue.
I used the developer tools of chrome and checked the network tab, found out the main reason why there are no errors being printed is because that the $(window).scroll(function(){... didn't have a closing tag before the .

Big thanks to Magnus Eriksson.